# Doing cleanup if app crashes

Tags: objective-c

I developed an application with Xcode 8.2 for OSX not iOS in objective c that helps controlling a third party application.

If my app crashes - I should do some cleanup (close documents in controlled app etc.).

Is there a way of NOT using a separate daemon app handling that?

I do not mean code exceptions, I already catch them with @try/@error blocks - I mean a crash.

Comment: If your app crashes there's really nothing it can do to clean *itself* up. It's crashed, it's not running code anymore. If you split your app into a simple launcher binary and the rest of your app, then the launcher can relaunch the part that crashed so it can clean up.

Comment: It doesn't have to clean itself up but the third party application.  I did some more research. There's no way except a daemon/launcher. Thank you